# Adding progressbar during a copying a large file using tcl fcopy

Tags: copy, progress-bar, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a Tcl/Tk based application where i need to send some large file from windows to a vm. I am using fcopy and it is working fine. But as the filesize may be big(in GBs), the application is blocked for 1 minute or more. As the proceeding operations depends on the copy of the file, I can not make this a non-blocking/background copy.

So I think of showing a progress bar to let the user know that the operation is in progress and to let them guess their waiting time(I don't plan to calculate this myself, user may guess this on their own). What is the way to achieve this ?I got a page where it is written "fcopy the file in chunks and update the interface" but failed to get anymore reference on it.

Is their any better alternative? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the `fcopy` documentation:

```
proc CopyMore {in out chunk bytes {error {}}} {
    global total done
    incr total $bytes
    if {$error ne "" || [eof $in]} {
        set done $total
        close $in
        close $out
    } else {
        # Add progress bar update here
        fcopy $in $out ‐size $chunk \
                ‐command [list CopyMore $in $out $chunk]
    }
}
set in [open $file1 rb];   # Wherever this comes from
set out [open $file2 wb];  # Wherever it is going to
set chunk 1024
set total 0
fcopy $in $out ‐size $chunk \
        ‐command [list CopyMore $in $out $chunk]
vwait done
```

All you need to do is add the update of the progress bar into there, and you've got the `total` number of bytes copied so far already.

Comment: So i have to change the size param value to chunk size=1024 in both end, right? BTW I am using similar functions like this link (http://wiki.tcl.tk/3094) in sending and receiving end.